# Insert nested structures in MongoDb with Golang

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have a question regarding storage in MongoDB using mgo.

My DB has this structure :

```
{
  "Arrival": [
    "04-09-2016"
  ],
  "Clicks": [
    "56ffd41d9c8c9adf088b4576",
    "4f1dc63a7c2d3817640000a1"
  ],
  "Recherches": [
    "érysipèle"
  ],
  "abonnements": {
    "newsletter": false
  },
  "compte": "Standard",
  "datei": ISODate("2016-09-04T14:55:39.179Z"),
  "email": "_°°°°_",
  "mdp": "27d8d166ca1f1715541b7df6453401b95a1d59c2ca0f60ce71037d33926c4d6f09a63a909a8d5cb5230f92584973a4dd2b8bcf155d5785ef7e2afdd113334eee",
  "type": "T&D",
  "user": "_°°°°_",
  "validation": "validé"
}
```

In my Go application the structures are :

```
type Abonnement struct {
    Newsletter bool bson:"newsletter"'
  }

type Persone struct {
    Compte string 'bson:"compte"'
    Datei time.Time 'bson:"datei"'
    Email string  'bson:"email"'
    MDP string 'bson:"mdp"'
    Type string 'bson:"T&D"'
    User string 'bson:"user"'
    Validation string 'bson:"validation"'
    Arrival []string 'bson:"Arrival"'
    Clicks []string 'bson:"Clicks"'
    Recherches []string 'bson:"Recherches"'
    Abonnements []Abonnement 'bson:"abonnements"'
  }
```

But I can't manage to create the variable to put everything together :

```
personita := Persone{
      Compte : "Standard",
      Datei : time.Date(2015, time.February, 12, 04, 11, 0, 0, time.UTC),
      Email : "test@test.com",
      MDP : "test_mdp",
      Type : "T&D",
      User : "test_user",
      Validation : "validé",
      Arrival  : []string{},
      Clicks : []string{},
      Recherches : []string{},
      Abonnements : []Abonnement{},
    }
```

My main goal would be that there's a default value when I insert 'personita' with this inside :

```
"abonnements": {
    "newsletter": false
  }
```

Comment: You're missing a {} at the end of []Abonnement

Comment: How can I add the default value for abonnements? "abonnements": { "newsletter": false }  @Sridhar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems just a typo

```
Abonnements : []Abonnement{}
```

Comment: How can I add the default value for abonnements? @uvelichitel

"abonnements": {
    "newsletter": false
  }

Comment: Abonnements :  []Abonnement{{false}}

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it creates : "abonnements": [ { "newsletter": false } ] and I would like : {"abonnements": { "newsletter": false } }

Comment: You define Abonnements as slice of Abonnement in Person struct. So it initialized as slice and than marshalled in bson array.

Comment: Ok, but if I do this : Abonnements Abonnement `bson:"abonnements"`
How can I add the default value this time ? https://puu.sh/r11A6/5925bdfa82.png

Comment: Abonnements : Abonnement{false}

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this. First define a function that returns a pointer to the structure:

```
func NewAbonnement()(ab *Abonnement){
    return &Abonnement{Newsletter: false}
}
```

Then call the function as Abonnement slice literal:

```
 personita := Persone{
      Compte : "Standard",
      Datei : time.Date(2015, time.February, 12, 04, 11, 0, 0, time.UTC),
      Email : "test@test.com",
      MDP : "test_mdp",
      Type : "T&D",
      User : "test_user",
      Validation : "validé",
      Arrival  : []string{},
      Clicks : []string{},
      Recherches : []string{},
      Abonnements : []Abonnement{*NewAbonnement()},
    }
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/K5UE4xC9TE)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it creates :
"abonnements": [ { "newsletter": false } ]

and I would like :
{"abonnements":  { "newsletter": false } }

Comment: In the edit I made a map, then marshaled the map to json and assigned the string to Abonnments as string.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for having Nested structures is to do:

```
type Abonnement struct {
  Newsletter bool `bson:"newsletter"`
  StripeID string `bson:"stripe_id,omitempty"`
  StripeSub string `bson:"stripe_sub,omitempty"`
}

type Personne struct {
  Compte string `bson:"compte"`
  Datei time.Time `bson:"datei"`
  Email string  `bson:"email"`
  MDP string `bson:"mdp"`
  Type string `bson:"T&D"`
  User string `bson:"user"`
  Validation string `bson:"validation"`
  Arrival []string `bson:"Arrival"`
  Clicks []string `bson:"Clicks"`
  Recherches []string `bson:"Recherches"`
  Abonnements Abonnement `bson:"abonnements"`
}
```

and then :

```
personita := Personne{
    Compte : "Standard",
    Datei : time.Date(2015, time.February, 12, 04, 11, 0, 0, time.UTC),
    Email : "test@test.com",
    MDP : "test_mdp",
    Type : "T&D",
    User : "test_user",
    Validation : "validé",
    Abonnements : Abonnement{false,"",""},
   }

if err := coll.Insert(personita); err != nil {panic(err)}
```

This way you have  the nested JSON added to MongoDB with default values.

Furthermore, in this particular case, StripeID or StripeSub are optional, hence if the value is empty they won't appear on your database.